# Getting data from nested json in SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm basically trying to extract data from a database with some conditionals and I'm running into a roadblock as I can't seem to get the statement right because I'm working with nested json. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    provider,
    data -> 'name',
    data -> 'email'  
FROM registrations
WHERE data ->> 'organization' = 'x'
OR data -> 'params' ->> 'organization' = 'x'
LIMIT 100;
```

I basically need to get the email from the database in all circumstances.  As you can see in the last lines, it sometimes might be at the top level of the json (which is called data), or it sometimes might be nested under 'params' like how organization is. So I want to have something like SELECT data -> email but if  data -> email ISNULL then select data -> 'params' ->> 'email'

How would I go about doing this, I imagine a CASE statement would be used but not sure how to use such conditionals in the first half of an SQL command like I did in the second. The json could have either of two structures as shown below:

```
{
    "cgu": "aa",
    "page": "bb",
    "email": "John@gmail.com",
    "action": "register",
    "name": "John doe"
)
```

OR

```
{
    "info": {
        "name": "John doe",
    },
    
    "params": {
        "page": "X",
        "portal": "cisco",
        "organization": "x",
        "email": "John@yahoo.com"
        
    }
}
```

Using the newest version of PostgreSQL on pgAdmin 4

Comment: Sure thing my bad, have added that info now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know where the `organization` key is located, you can use a [SQL/JSON Path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) query with the `@@` operator in the WHERE clause. To extract the actual value, use `jsonb_path_query_first()` in the SELECT list

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(data, 'strict $.**.email') #>> '{}' as email,
       jsonb_path_query_first(data, 'strict $.**.organization') #>> '{}' as organization
from registrations
where data @@ 'strict $.**.organization == "x"'
;
```

The `#>> '{}'` simply converts the `jsonb` value returned by the function to a `text` value. If you are OK with a `jsonb` value (which would include the double quotes), you can remove that part.

This assumes that the column `data` is defined as `jsonb` - which it should be. If it's not and you can't change your table, you will have to cast it: `data::jsonb`

The `strict` modifier for the JSON path expression is needed because otherwise the recursive operator `**` [doesn't work properly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#STRICT-AND-LAX-MODES).

Comment: That works! Thank you very much sir. Didn't know you could forcefully get to the root like that